# What does `[lang]` selector do?

Tags: css

What does `[lang]` selector do?

I have seen `[lang|="ar"]` but not `[lang]`.

Is it going to match any h1 with a lang attribute?

```
h1 [lang] {
font-style: italic;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See for yourself:

```css
h1 [lang] {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<h1>Empty</h1>

<h1>
  <span lang="en">en</span>
</h1>

<h1>
  <span lang>anything</span>
</h1>
```

The `[lang]` selector selects any element **within the `h1`** with a `lang` attribute.  In this case, it doesn't matter what the attribute's value is, only that it is present.

If you wanted to select any `h1` with a `lang` attribute, the selector would be `h1[lang]` (no space).

Comment: Is `<span lang>` valid html? `lang` without a value?

Comment: As long as you aren't in an XML namespace, it [appears to be valid](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-lang-and-xml:lang-attributes), but this is only after 60 seconds of research.

Comment: ` Its value must be a valid BCP 47 language tag, or the empty string.` But `<span lang>` is not an empty string. `<span lang="">` is.

Comment: According to [this contrived example](https://jsfiddle.net/qv601j9j/) the browser treats no value identically to an empty string.  I wouldn't worry about validation at this level though, it really doesn't matter that much anymore.  This is getting outside the scope of the question, though.

Comment: As far I know on HTML5 you can avoid the value just for [boolean attrs](http://w3c.github.io/html/infrastructure.html#sec-boolean-attributes)

Comment: @DaniP - That not correct. In the HTML syntax any attribute may use the [empty attribute syntax](http://w3c.github.io/html/syntax.html#elements-attributes) The spec says "The value is implicitly the empty string." The empty string is a valid value for the lang attribute.

Answer (score 0):

This would apply the style to every element with an attribute of lang in an h1 element - e.g. `<h1><span lang="eng">Hello World</span></h1>`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Answer (score 0):

This would select all elements that have a `lang` attribute, regardless of what it's specified to.

Comment: *all elements* -- inside `h1` ...that have